# Create folder and make ES File Explorer add icon of my app

Tags: android, mkdir

I want to associate folder with my application, like WhatsApp and Viber does.
I tried to create folder

```
File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/MyAppName");
folder.mkdir();
```

But that `MyAppName` folder is not associated with my app and ES File Explorer can't recognize "what app created the folder?", I want ES File Explorer add the icon of my app to the folder.

What is the way that some apps use for create folders and let ES File Explorer recognize the folders?

[image: ES File Explorer can recognize some folder with apps]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

All folders on Android are normal folders, ES File Explorer not uses any recognition system, people associates folders and every association is sent to ES File Explorer's database and majority of associations wins and finnaly folder is assigned with icon.

Comment: So that means, when a specific folder is present in a large number of users, the folder will be associated with the app icon, correct?

Comment: It means if a large number of users associate a folder with the same app and upload their choice, the folder will show the app icon because of at least 90% of choices.