# Create Thumbnail for folder in android

Tags: android, thumbnails

Can somebody please tell me how to create thumbnail just like Hike and Battery Doctor does? 
I have created new folder in internal storage with

```
File root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
                File Dir = new File(root.getAbsolutePath() + "/myfolder");
                if (!Dir.exists()) {
                    Dir.mkdir();

                }
```

`File Utility` does not have `setBackgroundDrawable` function as discussed in other posts. I tried copying .bmp image in created folder. Still such thumbnail does not show up.

EDIT:
All posts here in stackoverflow discusses about creating thumbail for images as in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5548645/get-thumbnail-uri-path-of-the-image-stored-in-sd-card-android) and for videos as in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7037630/how-to-create-a-video-preview-in-android). However I do not see any post regarding setting thumbnail for folder.

Thanks in advance!!!

[image: here]

Comment: Please include some code to show what you have tried.

Comment: It's not quite clear to me what you are trying to achieve. Could you describe your problem a bit more ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using ES File Explore to checking that? Because I found this post 
[Create folder and make ES File Explorer add icon of my app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30686248/create-folder-and-make-es-file-explorer-add-icon-of-my-app/31274611#31274611) 
Sorry because I don't have permission to add comment.